# How to implement if else in jmeter

Tags: if-statement, controller, jmeter

I need to implement below in jmeter

flag == 1

while (flag == 0)
check status 
   if status == successful
     Change the value of flag to 0
 check status 
   if status == failed
      Change the value of flag to 0
 check status

if status == in progress
      Change the value of flag to 0
  check status

if flag is 0 while loop should stop and user should go to next transaction

Comment: there's no else, all ifs can be unite because they are doing the same

Answer (score 0):

You don't need if-else in this situation, you can create the loop which will be executing its children using single [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter/) with the following condition (assumes [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)) :

```
${__groovy(!(vars.get('status').equals('success') || vars.get('status').equals('failure')),)}
```

- While Controller

  - Your request(s) here

Another option is going for [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), if you put `${status}` as the switch condition and organize your test plan like:

- Switch Controller

  - success
  - failure
  - in progress

You will be able to choose what happens depending on this or that `${switch}` variable value

make sure that requests define `status` variable

Comment: Hi Dmitri,thanks for help. I still have a doubt.
I am running a jdbc query ..in which job is running from that query i am extracting a value in parameter
those value are 1. success 2. processing 3.failed 
on success- i need to run another the query
On processing - i need to run the query again after some delay 
On failed- I have to stop the thread

Please help me how to implement this